# Provide RSS feeds for site specific newsletters

Tags: feature-request, feed, newsletter

I have been enjoying the new Stack Exchange site specific newsletters. While receiving the newsletters in my email works I still use an RSS reader and would rather consume the newsletter that way. Can an RSS feed for each newsletter be provided?

Comment: I'd really like this too, but mostly because my inbox is a disaster area. That's why I have not subscribed to the site specific newsletters, doing so would be counterproductive to my long term task of reducing noise in the place where stuff I'm supposed to do today often lands.