# "best of the week" emails as rss feeds etc

Tags: feature-request, feed, newsletter, atom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Provide RSS feeds for site specific newsletters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105979/provide-rss-feeds-for-site-specific-newsletters)

It would be really nice to have the content from the "best of the week" emails as RSS/Atom feeds: one item for each email (just like this is nice with any newsletter) and/or one item for each question in each email. Also, looking at the idea instead of its implemetation, the same would be nice with Twitter feeds and/or other syndication methods.

**Update:** As a side-note, it would be useful to have syndication stuff wherevever emails are used, possibly vice-versa; and not only with email, but with other things too, automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something similar to this with [Stack2RSS](http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com), an application I wrote that pulls data from the Stack Exchange API and converts it into an RSS feed. In your case, this would look something like:

> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow.com/questions?body=true&sort=week

This will return the top 30 questions for the week from Stack Overflow. You can easily change 'stackoverflow.com' in the URL to the domain name of any other Stack Exchange site.